# The bean conflicts in Spring. How to solve this question？

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**question:**
A dependency of a project has a class with the same name as the class contained in the project itself, thus causing a conflict. How do I fix this?

```
2022-09-19 13:32:21,109 main ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication858  - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.learnyeai.BaseApiApplication]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'redisConfig' for bean class [com.learnyeai.common.redis.RedisConfig] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.learnyeai.jsstudy.config.RedisConfig]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.learnyeai.BaseApiApplication.main(BaseApiApplication.java:18)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'redisConfig' for bean class [com.learnyeai.common.redis.RedisConfig] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.learnyeai.jsstudy.config.RedisConfig]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:348)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:286)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:132)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:287)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

[com.learnyeai.common.redis.RedisConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuW3O.png)

[com.learnyeai.jsstudy.config.RedisConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6UUW.png)

Comment: why don't you just change your custom RedisConfig class name to something else?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can name your bean:

```
@Bean(name = "anotherRedisConfig")
```

or easier:

```
@Bean("anotherRedisConfig")
```